# Toggle new tab and popup in options.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was curious to see if anyone had any experience with allowing the user to turn off or on the new tab chrome_url_override.

I am currently developing an extension that loads the content when a new tab is opened, but would also like to have the option of turning the new tab functionality off and allowing the user to use the extension as a popup located on the toolbar.

I would prefer not to separate this between two extensions, so if anyone has done or seen anything like this that would be a tremendous amount of help.

Comment: Technically, this is against the Web Store policies.

Answer (score 0):

Nope! you will need to do it manually, unfortunately.  If it helps, the new tab returns `www.google.com` with `location.hostname` so your scripts could use this to detect a new tab.

Hope it helps!